# Prevent Bootstrap popover from resetting content on show

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, popover, fancytree

I am using a bootstrap popover to display an instance of fancytree. On the initial click of the button that triggers the popover, everything loads and initializes correctly.The user can select items in the tree, search for items in the tree, etc. When the popover is dismissed and then shown for the second (or more) time, only the original static html that was in the data-content attribute is shown. After looking at the DOM while this happens, it appears that the popover is just replacing the dynamically generated content that fancytree created with the static content in the data-content attribute.

My question is, is there a way/option for the popover to not reinitialize the content every time it is displayed and just hide it instead?

Because I have an instance of fancytree created dynamically, I can't just swap out the HTML as it would no longer "link" to the fancytree object.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: FWIW there is a pop-up demo (jquery-confirm) on the Fancytree project site: http://wwwendt.de/tech/fancytree/demo/#sample-3rd-confirm.html

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution to the issue of preventing the bootstrap popover from re-initializing the content inside of it but I did end up going with the bootstrap dropdown instead since the content that is displayed by it does not get reset every time a user opens it.